# How do I assign a TextBox value to a variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

```
lbl1 = Label(root, text="Target:").pack()
box1 = Entry(root).pack()
lbl2 = Label(root, text="Port:").pack()
box2 = Entry(root).pack()

ps_target = #value given to box1
```

I'm trying to make the value I give box1 to appear on my 'ps_target' variable. How do I do this? I'm using the Tkinter module in Python 2.7.6.

If you need more detail please let me know I will give as much as possible.

Comment: ps_target .set(box1.get())

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "test.py", line 49, in port_scan
    ps_target .set(ebox1.get())
NameError: global name 'ps_target' is not defined                        /:

Comment: try the link @Leon shared

Comment: is ps_target just a variable to string the value from box1?

Comment: no its in a different string "def port_scan(self)"

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems, first you should be calling pack separately. Instead of

```
box1 = Entry(root).pack()
```

You should do

```
box1 = Entry(root)
box1.pack()
```

To get the value from `box` you then call `get`

```
box1.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Entry(root).pack()`  means packing an entry in the parent widget `root`. This returns none to `box1`. It makes no sense to assign a `none` object to a new variable.
So if you want to operate this entry object, you should write like this:

```
my_entry = Entry(root)
my_entry.pack()
# do anything you like to my_entry here like my_entry.winfo_width()
```